# Teams FX Project upgrade

Tags: teams-toolkit

We have created our Teams FX project using Teams Toolkit v 3.7.0 and we have already released our app to the production.

TeamsFX CLI version from package.json: "@microsoft/teamsfx-cli": "^0.14.0",
TeamsFX API version from package-lock.json:  "@microsoft/teamsfx-api": {"version": "0.18.0",

Now, we would like to upgrade the project to latest version. I have gone through wiki articles but it's not very clear. Can you please let us know the upgrade procedure. Is updating the Teams toolkit version to latest version enough or any other additional steps required.
Please let us know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Latest VSCode teams toolkit extension or teamsfx cli already support migration.

If you're using VSCode, you can open the project,  then you will see the dialog as below, click upgrade, it will automatically upadte your project to latest version:

[image]

If you're using TeamsFx CLI, you can run preview or provision command in the project, then it will ask you to upgrade app:

[image]

> Tip: due to there is a bug for upgrade in recent version, recommend using latest version 4.0.5 to avoid migration issue.

Comment: Hi @SLdragon, Thanks a lot for your response. So this upgrade takes care of everything? Don't we have to explicitly update the packages @microsoft/teamsfx-api and @microsoft/teamsfx-cli as specified in the github wiki. And any other steps to be followed after this for existing projects to work.Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Hi, upgrade only take care of project structure, and add/move/remove some materials which relevant to project settings, and it doesn't touch your owner code. You project should works as before, and however, if you want to update the SDK and use new features of our sdk, you can follow the docs to update it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/teamsfx-sdk#upgrade-latest-sdk-version